# How can I check the port py.test is using

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pytest

I'm running py.test on PyCharm COMMUNITY 2017.3. How can I check the port py.test is using.
Or let me know the default port of py.test. 
Because I want to inspect my bug with command `nc -l xxxx`. Thanks.

Comment: `pytest` does not allocate any ports by default. It must be either the code you're running, or a plugin for `pytest`.

Comment: Thank you. I will continue to look it up.